# Insertion sort on strings

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I was trying to sort an array of strings according to their middle three characters using insertion sort.

the code compiles but crashes while running

i am sorting the array of middle 3 character and also sorting an array which stores the index of the strings.
so that while printing the final result i can get a sorted array

```
void ins(string a[size],int n)
{
    int i,j,k,length[size],index[size],m,t;
    string temp,ts[size];      // ts[] stores the middle 3 characters
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        index[i]=i;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        length[i]=a[i].length();
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        m=length[i]/2;
        ts[i]=a[i].substr(m-1,3);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<ts[i]<<endl;
    for(k=1;k<n;k++)
    {
        temp=ts[k];
        t=index[k];
        j=k-1;
        while((temp < ts[j]) && (j>=0))
        {
            ts[j+1]=ts[j];
            index[j+1]=index[j];
            j=j-1;
        }

        ts[j+1]=temp;
        index[j+1]=t;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[index[i]]<<endl;
    }
}
```

main

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k,num;
    string a[size];
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    ins(a,n);
}
```

can you please help me find the bug

Comment: Is `n` the same value as `size`?

Comment: n is the total strings

Comment: Where does your code crash? I suspect that if your strings are of length 1 or 0, you'll end up passing `-1` to `substr`, which generates an exception. But I'd like you to be more specific.

Comment: i tried checking .. the problem seems to be in the while loop..and i am only passing strings with more than three length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an expression of the form `left-condition && right-condition`:

1. The *left-condition* is evaluated first;
2. What happens next depends on the result of the evaluation of the *left-condition*:

   1. If the *left-condition* is true, the *right-condition* is evaluated in second.
   2. If the *left-condition* is false, the evaluation of the *right-condition* is skipped.

In your case, the problems lies with the expression `(temp < ts[j]) && (j>=0)` since it implements the following behavior:

1. You first use `ts[j]` in the left expression;
2. Then you test in the right-expression that `j>=0`, so that `ts[j]` would not be out-of-bounds.

The solution simply is to exchange the positions of these expressions and to write the expression as: `(j >= 0 && temp < ts[j])`.